# How to fix issue TrustManager android application rejected by Google play

Tags: android, google-play

I try to launch apps on playstore and it rejected, 
caused of X509TrustManager, i don't know what is it,  but I guess it caused of in the apps i try to access API with HTTP not HTTPS, is my guess correct??

if I try to force to call API with HTTP how could I fix this issue, so that my Apps accepted by google?

this my reject email come from google play. can anyone explain me what is it actually and how could I do?

[image]

Comment: What is the actual targeted SDK version and minimum sdk version in your app

Comment: It's exactly what you think it is, You cannot call any API over HTTP, preferred mode is HTTPS.
So, if you made the API, it's better to migrate it to HTTPS protocol, or some old libraries, try using HTTP instead of HTTPS. So, try removing those or updating them.

Comment: How did you solved this issue? I am also getting the same issue from many days.

Comment: you have resolved this issue ?